# Suggest parameters in IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

when I type a method call  into intellij it doesn't suggest parameters, is it possible to make it suggest parameters?

for example calling

```
void setFoo( Foo foo );
```

in context

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
dto.setFoof(...
```

could then either prepopulate or suggest foo (netbeans does this).

Also parameters, like boolean could suggest, true or false.

Is it possible to make it suggest them, without additional typing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (Parameter Info) to get a tooltip showing an abstract of all parameters for all overloaded variants of a method (place the caret on the method). When using code completion (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) or SmartType (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) inside the method's parentheses, IntelliJ tries to intelligently propose parameter values that fit in the current context (such as `true` or `false` or a method yielding `true` or `false` for a boolean parameter).

In the Settings dialog (Settings... -> Editor -> Code Completion) you can configure the Parameter Info feature by activating an autopopup or enabling showing full signatures.